# In Bash, how do I safely determine what a soft link points to?

Tags: bash, symlink

I need to process a number of directories, determine what files in them are symlinks, and what they link to. This sounds simple, but I have no control over the presence of control or other characters in the file names, and I need a robust solution.

So, given a file of arbitrary name, how do I safely determine what it links to, when the link destination can also have arbitrary contents?

Comment: Something related was also asked on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167631/1174).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
readlink -f <linkname>
```

See the readlink(1) man page for [Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&sektion=1), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/readlink.1), [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/readlink.1), [DragonFly](https://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=readlink&section=1) or the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html) info page.

Comment: I didn't use the `-f` option in mac because it gave me an error `readlink: illegal option -- f`

Comment: @JonathanMoralesVélez - that only matters if you have a link to another link and want the final non-symlink file.  If that matters, install Homebrew and use the GNU version of readlink.

Answer (score 6):

```
stat <linkname>
```

**Example:**

```
stat /usr/local/cuda
```

First 2 lines will give:

```
File: '/usr/local/cuda' -> 'cuda-8.0'
Size: 8             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
...
```

Comment: Important not to include a closing `/`, i.e. `stat /usr/local/cuda`, not `stat /usr/local/cuda/`.